# Get the same results from string.start_with? and string[ ]

Tags: ruby, string, methods, startswith

Basically, I want to check if a string (`main`) starts with another string (`sub`), using both of the above methods. For example, following is my code:

```ruby
main = gets.chomp
sub = gets.chomp

p main.start_with? sub
p main[/^#{sub}/]
```

And, here is an example with I/O - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzcxM0/BViE9taRYLzkjP7eAq7g0CVWAq0ABpEqvuCSxqCS@PLMkw14BqAgqHK0fp1wN5Nbqx/7/bxhjZMAFJAA)

---

If I enter *simple* strings, then both of them works exactly the same, but when I enter strings like `"1\2"` in `stdin`, then I get errors in the Regexp variant, as seen in TIO example.

I guess this is because of the reason that the string passed into second one isn't **raw**. So, I tried passing `sub.dump` into second one - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzcxM0/BViE9taRYLzkjP7eAq7g0CVWAq0ABpEqvuCSxqCS@PLMkw14BqAgqHK0fp1wN5OqllOYW1OrH/v9vGGNkwAUkAA)

which gives me `nil` result. How to do this correctly?

Comment: The reflex check appears designed to return the first match, not a Boolean of whether or not it matches. What you can do is capitalise on all objects in Ruby other than nil and false being “truthy”. So if you put this in an if statement, it will work the same way. Or you could prefix it with two big characters (!!) if you really want a Boolean.

Comment: Or you could just use string.match(/^foo/)

Comment: @AJFaraday - I think you misunderstood a bit, I can use `!!` obviously, but in the second link, the regex method fails to match, even if the `sub` is a substring of `main`. I want to ensure both of them work correctly, not that both of them give the exact output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you should *never ever* blindly execute inputs from untrusted sources.

Interpolating untrusted input into a [`Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) is not quite as bad as interpolating it into, say, [`Kernel#eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), because the worst thing an attacker can do with a `Regexp` is to construct an *Evil Regex* to conduct a [*Regular expression Denial of Service (ReDoS)*](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) attack (see also the section on [*Performance*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Performance) in the `Regexp` documentation), whereas with `eval`, they could execute arbitrary code, including but not limited to, deleting the entire file system, scanning memory for unencrypted passwords / credit card information / PII and exfiltrate that via the network, etc.

However, it is still a bad idea. For example, when I say "the worst thing that happen is a ReDoS", that assumes that there are no bugs in the `Regexp` implementation ([Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) in the case of [YARV](http://atdot.net/yarv), [Joni](https://github.com/jruby/joni) in the case of [JRuby](https://jruby.org/) and [TruffleRuby](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby), etc.) Ruby's `Regexp`s are quite powerful and thus Onigmo, Joni and co. are large and complex pieces of code, and may very well have their own security holes that could be used by a specially crafted `Regexp`.

You should properly sanitize and escape the user input *before* constructing the `Regexp`. Thankfully, the Ruby core library already contains a method which does exactly that: [`Regexp::escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape). So, you could do something like this:

```ruby
p main[/^#{Regexp.escape(sub)}/]
```

The reason why your attempt at using [`String#dump`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-dump) didn't work, is that `String#dump` is for representing a `String` the same way you would have to write it as a `String` literal, i.e. it is escaping *`String`* metacharacters, not *`Regexp`* metacharacters *and* it is including the quote characters around the `String` that you need to have it recognized as a `String` literal. You can easily see that when you simply try it out:

```ruby
sub.dump
#=> "\"1\\\\2\""
# equivalent to '"1\\2"'
```

So, that means that `String#dump`

- includes the quotes (which you don't want),
- escapes characters that don't need escaping in `Regexp` just because they need escaping in `String`s (e.g. `#` or `"`), and
- *doesn't* escape characters that don't need escaping in `String`s (e.g. `[`, `.`, `?`, `*`, `+`, `^`, `-`).